# Porblem with Axios request in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, axios

I am trying to launch a post Axios request from my front to my back using React framework. When I use my localhost server its works but I use Heroku address, I have an error message (400 bad request) in my console.
I tried to launch other get Axios requests with heroku and it works. So I am wondering that the problem I have is related to Post Axios requests. 
I will appreciate your comments

please find below my code (front react):

```
import React from "react";

import axios from "axios";

const Questions = () => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://formnest-back-certification.herokuapp.com/form/create",
      {
        title: "nouveau formulaire",
      }
    );

    console.log(response.data);
  };

  fetchData();

  return (
    <>
      <div>Hello form</div>
    </>
  );
};
export default Questions;
```

Here is my code in the back React:

```
router.post("/form/create", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    /* const titleForm = await Form.findOne({ title: req.fields.title });
    console.log(titleForm);

    if (titleForm) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "title already used" });
    } else { */
    if (req.fields.title) {
      const newForm = new Form({
        title: req.fields.title,
        /* questions: req.fields.questions,
          answers: req.fields.answers, */
      });

      // Sauvegarde du formulaire
      await newForm.save();
      return res.json(newForm);
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Missing parameters" });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: e.message });
  }
  /*  console.log(req.fields); */
  /* 
  res.json({ message: "form created" }); */
});
```

[image: Screen shot of my console further to my post axios request]

Comment: There might be some error in backend, can you post the error?

Comment: @eason I do not have any error in the back. the error appears in my console in the front.

Comment: does the backend respond properly when using postman ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express framework for the POST request, you need to using `body-parser` module then using `req.body` to retrieve the request data.

req.fields is when you are using `express-formidable` module.

Comment: Thanks for your message. If I understood well, I need to install body-parser module and req.body for the POST axios requests. What about express-formidable ? Is it useful for GET requests ?